# MVC Attribute routing, redirecting old urls

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have just upgraded from MVC 4 to 5 and started using attribute routing.
It works perfect and is easy to implement.

But since the website has been up for a few months theres a number of links to the website, including from search engines.
The old urls will not work so I need to redirect them permanently.
I'm not sure what the best way would be. I thought that if I created a route in the route.config, this would work as a backup for the routing attribute. But it seems to be only one that works (first served).

Example.. 
Old url: /bank/5
New url: /superbank/5

The attribute route looks like this:

```
[Route("superbank/{id}")]
```

And the route.config:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

routes.MapRoute(
            "BankDetails",
            "bank/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "bank" }, //the action is still called bank, not superbank
            new { id = @"^\d+$" } 
);
```

With this code, only superbank/5 will work, not bank/5
If I put MapMvcAttributeRoutes() beneath the MapRoute, neither of the urls will work and all urls in the project will be created and pointing to bank/5.

Any ideas?
Should I use global.asax or IIS url rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I came up with a solution. It might not be the best one but it works.

In RouteConfig.cs, I added a "catchall" route. It now looks like this:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            "",
            "{catchall*}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "NotFound" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "BankDetails",
            "bank/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "bank" },
            new { id = @"^\d+$" } 
        );
```

I then added an action NotFound in my Home controller:

```
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        string url = Request.Url.ToString();
        url = url.Replace("/bank/", "/superbank/");
        url = url.Replace("old-page-name", "new-page-name"); //Just to demonstrate

        if (url != Request.Url.ToString())
            return RedirectPermanent(url);
        else
            return Redirect("404page");
    }
```

This works fine. You just have to be careful not to replace a too generic name.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have that one route (with the `id` parameter) to redirect, I would just create an action method and take care of the redirect there:

```
[Route("bank/{id}")]
public ActionResult Bank(int id)
{
    return RedirectToActionPermanent("superbank", new { id });
}
```

Comment: I don't want to rename the action and I can't create two actions, one with route bank/{id} and one with superbank/{id}. And theres not only one action, it's about 30 in total :)